# Function of canonical correlations of two vectors

Tags: statistics

Let the random vector $X = \{X^T_1,X^T_2\}$. Lets say that $G$ is transformation group such that $G = \{Y = Y_1^T, Y_2^T\mid Y_i=A_i X_i+b_i, i=1,2\}$, where $A_1,A_2,(b_1,b_2)$ can take any value from the set of non-random matrices(vectors). How to show that any function invariant to $G$ i.e $\forall$ $Y\in G$ $f(EX,DX) = f(EY,DY)$, is a function of canonical correlations of vectors $X_1$ and $X_2$?